# intersect of two lists results in an empty list

Tags: c#, linq, intersect

I have two lists

```
List<clsEntity> usersWithNPIRCodingPermission // It has count 159
List<clsEntity> usersWithRaiseReq // It has count 219
```

When doing intersect on these (there are 55 records but my below line getting empty list)

```
List<clsEntity> users = usersWithRaiseReq.Intersect(usersWithNPIRCodingPermission).ToList();
```

Why is the resulting `users` list empty?

Comment: Is that really the right code? You're talking about an intersect, but you're using the `Except` method and not `Intersect`.

Comment: Does `clsEntity` implement `IEquatable<T>`? If not, this is only going to `ReferenceEquals` for each element. You should definitely post a [mcve] so we can help.

Comment: Are the additional 60 instances just repeats of other instances in the list?

Comment: Also Intersec and Except make use of Equalitycomparison. So if you have multiple elements that are Equal you cannot rely on Count of the list to verify your results.

Comment: `Intersect()` and `Except()` use `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`, so make sure you implement those correctly, or implement an `EqualityComparer<clsEntity>` and give that to `Intersect`/`Except` as a parameter.

Comment: sorry it's not except/....I mean usersWithRaiseReq.intersect(usersWithNPIRCodingPermission).ToList();

Comment: would you care to edit the question and accept the answer?

Comment: I have edited question but I can not mark answer as I am new, have not got 15 reputations yet.

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement an equality comparer for your type if it's not a primitive e.g. `int` etc...

```
public class UsersComparer : IEqualityComparer<clsEntity>
{
    public bool Equals(clsEntity x, clsEntity y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return x.ID == y.ID; // or whatever you use to determine equality
    }

    public int GetHashCode(clsEntity x)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return 0;

        return x.ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<clsEntity> users = usersWithRaiseReq.Except(
      usersWithNPIRCodingPermissionn, new UsersComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: This worked...now its getting intersect of two lists...Thank you so much for your help

Comment: If this answers your question consider [accepting it as the answer](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjd2r71k-PJAhUKuxQKHQHqBuMQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F5234%2Fhow-does-accepting-an-answer-work&usg=AFQjCNFG4vSQJ4mHJvESivMd4xw8UphR_Q&bvm=bv.110151844,d.ZWU)

Comment: Once I get 15 reputations I will mark it as answer as It's not allowing me to mark for now..thanks for your help again